# What should I use to create a site which is part CMS, part video streaming, part e-learning in php/mysql

Tags: php, joomla, moodle

I need to create a site that has these basic requirements:

- Standard CMS function (nothing very advanced) for presenting the pages to
  the user. What Joomla does without
  any modification is OK, or even too
  much
- Abilty to stream videos stored on my
  server
- Advanced E-learning capabilities

What do you suggest? For the E-learning part I was thinking about [moodle](http://moodle.org/about/) but I've never used it and I don't know how difficult it is to configure it to suit my needs.

Otherwise I'd use Joomla, but I don't know if there are valid plugins for the e-learning - video streaming part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 if you know Joomla! go Joomla!

You need Learning Management System. Have a look at Joomlearn LMS and JoomlaLMS.

Usually choice depends on your 'budget'. There are several systems that are free (Moodle, Ilias, etc) and they have bridges with Joomla. If you do NOT have the expertise with bridges, you wind up paying as much for "outside help" with Moodle or Ilias as you would just going with a native solution to start with.

If you need a full Joomla solution and can afford it go with JoomlaLMS. It is the most powerful solution for a native Joomla. It offers "more than plenty" features for any folk who wants to operate an online learning portal. No problems with streaming videos stored on your server, advanced reporting options, eCommerce options, VirtueMart and JomSocial integration, ...

Joomlearn LMS can go as simple LMS. It has all the basic features, no advanced ones. Much simplier and cheaper than JoomlaLMS. So, it depends on your needs and budget.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I have gone off of the main-stream open source CMSs and built my own, if you know Joomla! go Joomla! is my advice. I have 1 installation current and because the number of pages don't change just content the editor of the site uses the front end login to do the updates. 
WordPress is worth looking at if you want a reasonably decent alternative.

There are plenty of apps to stream video using Flash, because we don't know what features you really need just do a quick hunt on google for a flash video player.

Finally moodle, I like this application but it does have a fairly large number of variables when you're configuring it. Highly flexible and functional under a variety of usages.

For each of these applications hosted solutions are also available, so you could get a cloud hosted solution and manage DNS with your domain name supplier.